Past simple instead of past continuous 4
I know how to use past simple and continuous. First shorter actions, second longer actions.
1 I was cooking when she came in
2 I was cooking while she was playing
But what if I do this
3 I cooked when she came in
4 I cooked while she played
Are my sentences interchangeable? How do you feel about them?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144705/while-followed-by-simple-past-past-continuous has some good answers. To me 4) works and 3) doesn't - "she came in" isn't a simultaneous, continuous action.

Please punctuate your sentences properly. We are not texting here. You did something when something else happened. OR You were doing it when it happened. That's how these work for your purposes here.

@Maciej Stachowski. Dzięki


3 I cooked when she came in

Suggests that you started cooking after she came in. Not the same as being in the process of cooking when she came in.

4 I cooked while she played

This means the same as 2. You could also use

“I was cooking while she played”

and the meaning remains intact.
The difference is of course the act of her coming in is a moment in time whereas playing occurs over a period of time.

Don't you think this “I was cooking while she played” is a little ambigious as if she interrupted my cooking with playing?

I wouldn’t say so.
